# App Script to generate copy of sheets by ID to a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a new public school technology integration specialist. My predecessor was heavy into Google Sheets and App Scripts and created a whole bunch of stuff and I'm trying to keep up.  We have these Google Sheet books where we have a template that we want to make copies of for each student that will get placed in a folder. All tof the script generated copies communicate back to a teacher dashboard sheet. I have done a few of these already this year and did not have any problems running the script and having it work.

Today, I went to try it again and I accidentally put in the wrong folder ID (added too much of the url).  Now, when I try to run the script to generate copies for the students I get this error message even though I fixed the folder ID.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV21t.png)

[image]

I believe my error is in line 22.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdyhp.png)

[image]

I fixed the folder ID where I orginally entered it. I tried making copies of the Sheets, changing owners, and rerunning the script. Didn't work. I also tried looking the script for the error looking at the Execution Log. I've also gotten this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3aaO.png)

[image]

which I Think is here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIw7k.png)

[image]

I am very new to this so any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clearly there is something wrong with the id for the dest_folder.

Comment: Is `range` in the second image a named range that comes from some other function?